# Why does reading data from Cassandra using Python fail with ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingInputFormat?

Tags: python, cassandra, apache-spark

I have install cassandra and running in host `127.0.0.1`

I follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/cassandra_inputformat.py), using cqlsh I have create `keyspace demo` and `cf userpage`. And refer from tutorial, I run:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit cassandra_inputformat.py 127.0.0.1 demo userpage
```

but it's appear error :

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingInputFormat
```

I frustated with this, i have config connector pyspark to cassandra from http://spark-packages.org/package/TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra

and put

```
spark.executor.extraClassPath      $SPARK_HOME/lib/pyspark-cassandra-0.1.5.jar
```

in file `spark-defaults.conf`

what i miss ? please help

thx

NB :

- Spark version 1.4.1
- Cassandra 2.1.9
- pyspark-cassandra Package Version: 0.1.5

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you solve it?